# How to create sorted dict by sorting nested dictionary based on length of value dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
{'M61': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options'},
'VAMP': {'21': 'Y'} }
```

I want to create a sorted dictionary based on this type of dictionary.

Based on the length of the dictionary inside.

So my final output should look like

```
{'VAMP': {'21': 'Y'},
 'M61': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options'}
}
```

Like VAMP have only 1 key-value pair inside and M61 have 2

I tried

```
sorted_dict = sorted (DictA, key = lambda inner_dict: len (inner_dict ["i"]))
```

But failed miserably any idea how can I achieve it?

Comment: A `dict` is meant for storing keys and values, not ordering. If you want an ordered dict, do `from collections import OrderedDict`.

Comment: Yeah sorry Sorting only @GeeTransit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort using `dict.items()` on the number of keys in each sub-dictionary as the `key`

```
DictA = {   'M61': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options'},
            'VAMP': {'21': 'Y'},
            'VAMP2': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options', '20': 'options', '22': 'options'},
            'M62': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options', '20': 'options'}
        }

#Sort of dict.items using length of keys of subdictionary as a key
print(dict(sorted(DictA.items(), key=lambda kv:len(kv[1]))))
```

The output will be

```
{'VAMP': {'21': 'Y'}, 
'M61': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options'}, 
'M62': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options', '20': 'options'}, 
'VAM2': {'12': 'options', '14': 'options', '20': 'options', '22': 'options'}}
```

Comment: what about the reverse ?

Comment: You can set `reverse=True` in [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) @Ivank